# How to merge or consolidate data from two datasources?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm not sure whether is this a good place for this kind of question, but I haven't got a better idea.

I am dealing with financial OHLC (+Volume) data (basically they are time series) in my python/pandas project, where some records may miss from any dataset or can be an outlier. 
The data comes from two different data sources (only!) and there are some differences between them.

I wan't to improve the quality of the data, somehow merge the information from the two datasoures or multiple time series and always give back an approximately correct OHLC (+Volume) information regarding to the queried symbol for the given datetime interval.

If there would be at least three data sources, I could do some weighted linear approximation or use a voting based mechanism, but what can I do if I only have two datasources?

Comment: Can you please give several sample rows and the result you would expect from running your desired process on those rows. I understand you also want to add a column with information on the validity of the stitching. Please add that as well.